# Django ManyToMany Relationship can't access fields

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a list model that uses `User` as foreign key twice.

The 1st is as `ForeignKey` to the creator. And 2nd as `ManyToManyField` for users for that list

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1,related_name='created_by')
    list_users = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='list_users')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.SlugField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='active', max_length=10)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

What I want to do is:

1. Get the users for the list.
2. Get the list for the logged in user.

Here is my code for #1:

```
todolist = get_object_or_404(TodoList, slug=list_slug)
users = todolist.list_users
```

The first line works fine. But when I get the `list_users` it will return `auth.User.None` even though the list has 3 users added to it through admin.

Here is my code for #2:

```
user = request.user
user_todo_lists = user.todolist.all()
```

The page will send an:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'todolist'

but when I rename the `list_users` to `user`. It will work just fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: *The page will send an AttributeError saying 'User' object has no attribute 'todolist'* When you say `related_name='list_users'` you tell django that you want `User`to have a related field with name `list_users` pointing to a set of `TodoList`s, hence it's `user.list_users`, but it should probably be `related_name='todos'` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @dhke. I'm new to django so I'm not really familiar with it. Thansk for the tip on related_name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first problem, you probably want `todolist.list_users.all()`. (That is, you want a `QuerySet`, not a `Manager`.)

Regarding your second problem, I'm not sure which relation you're actually trying to get at, but in either case you need to use the attribute defined by `related_name`. (That is, `user.created_by.all()` or `user.list_users.all()`.)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I forgot about the .all() part. And I just ready about how to user related name.